# Exporting a brightway project

Tags: brightway

I am changing computer and would like to keep some projects with me.

I know where the project folders/files are located (`C:\Users\AwesomeUser\AppData\Local\pylca\Brightway3`), and hence where to copy them, but am unsure how to add them to `projects.db`

What is the best practice for moving projects across computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `backup_project_directory` and `restore_project_directory` functions in Brightway2-IO ([see source code for usage](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/8d049d76f50b7d8be67a67e508704ac324fd53ff/bw2io/backup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)).